# Mantener los datos de un formulario en las distintas capas de view

Tags: python, sql, flask

He creado una plataforma con python y flask, en la primera pantalla aparece un login con el correo y contraseña de usuario y hace un check en la base de datos para comprobar si existe el usuario y darle acceso.

Después cuándo el usuario se mueve por dentro de la plataforma va entrando en otras capas del view.

No encuentro la forma de poder almacenar la información del correo y contraseña del principio para poder utilizarla en consultas en otras capas.

Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias
UPDATE: Lo que necesito saber es que si extraigo una información a través de un formulario en una pestaña de la web como puedo almacenar esta información para poder utilizarla en otra pestaña

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola rexxarcat lo he actualizado

Comment: Eso fue un comentario automático, lo que salió quería decir es que para hacer una pregunta normalmente metes un código reproducible de ejemplo de lo que tienes sin datos personales.

Comment: Usa las sesiones de flask